# Split XML File and extract certain datasets

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I try to extract the values (Distance and Angle) out of this Xml File. As this is not the problem I have an issue with splitting the datasets (divided by Attribute Feldsatz in Node Area).
I need a function which splits the XML File and just passes the values from the belonging Dataset into the variable to go on with it.

If anybody could give me a hand it would be much appreciated.

Code (error CS0103: The name 'innerXml' does not exist in the current context):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class PolygonTester : MonoBehaviour
{
public void Start()
{
//Load XML - File
TextAsset txtXmlAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("ftProtect");
//New Doc for the Text  
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
//Pass in the Text
doc.LoadXml(txtXmlAsset.text);

//Choice of situation 
XmlNodeList Index = doc.SelectNodes("/Field/Area[@Feldsatz]");

foreach (XmlNode Feldsatz in Index)
{
if (Feldsatz.Attributes["Feldsatz"].Value == "1")
{
string innerXml = Feldsatz.InnerXml;  <---------------------------------Error
}
}       
//Navigating to Node
XmlNodeList xnList = innerXml.SelectNodes("/Field/Area/UserPointList/UserPoint[@Distance]");

//Initializing
var j = xnList.Count;

Vector2[] vertices2D = new Vector2[j + 1];
string distanceHelper;
string angleHelper;
var k = 0;

foreach (XmlNode node in xnList)
{
//distance read out and convert to float
distanceHelper = node.Attributes["Distance"].Value;
double flt1 = double.Parse(distanceHelper);
//cm in m 
double radius = flt1 / 100;

//angle read out and convert to float
angleHelper = node.Attributes["Angle"].Value;
double flt2 = double.Parse(angleHelper);
//shift from 0 is 45°
double shift = flt2 + 45;
//fromdeg to rad
double rad = shift * (Math.PI / 180);

//Polar to Kartesian (double da Math.cos/sin nur double kann)
double x_value = radius * Math.Cos(rad);
double y_value = radius * Math.Sin(rad);

//vector2 will float werte 
float a = (float)x_value;
float b = (float)y_value;

//read Value pairs into the array
vertices2D[k] =  new Vector2(a, b);
k = k + 1;
    }

....
```

Xml - File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 -<Field Type="ftProtect">
  -<Area Feldsatz="1">
   -<UserPointList>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="57" Angle="0"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="50" Angle="81,5"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="50" Angle="187,5"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="56" Angle="270"/>
   </UserPointList>
  </Area>
 -<Area Feldsatz="2">
  -<UserPointList>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="57" Angle="0"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="50" Angle="81,5"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="32" Angle="115,5"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="80" Angle="128"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="80" Angle="142,5"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="32" Angle="155"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="50" Angle="187,5"/>
    <UserPoint Contour="FALSE" Distance="56" Angle="270"/>
   </UserPointList>
  </Area>
 </Field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error is that you are defining `innerXML` inside the `foreach` loop and then trying to access it outside of that loop on the line

```
XmlNodeList xnList = innerXml.SelectNodes("/Field/Area/UserPointList/UserPoint[@Distance]");
```

You need to define the variable outside of the scope of the `foreach` loop in order to use it elsewhere.

Example:

```
string innerXml = "";
foreach (XmlNode Feldsatz in Index)
{
    if (Feldsatz.Attributes["Feldsatz"].Value == "1")
    {
        innerXml = Feldsatz.InnerXml;  
    }
}       

XmlNodeList xnList = innerXml.SelectNodes("/Field/Area/UserPointList/UserPoint[@Distance]");
```

Comment: when innerXml is declared a string its not possible to use .SelectNodes. It has to be XmlNode, but everytime I try to adjust this it gives me the error "error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Xml.XmlNode'" for the line innerXml = Feldsatz.InnerXml;

Comment: @Micha but that's just what you wrote in your code .. Gunarhawk is just telling you that the `string` has to be declared outside of the loop to fix the problem of your question ... That it isn't even assignable to `string` at all is actually a follow up issue which is not scope of this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66534474/7111561)

Why even use a loop? What you want is the first entry that matches your condition so you can use e.g. [Linq `FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault)

```
using System.Linq;

...

var Feldsatz = Index.FirstOrDefault(feldsatz => feldsatz.Attributes["Feldsatz"].Value == "1");
if(Feldsatz == null)
{
    Debug.LogError("Couldn't find Feldsatz");
    return;
}

string innerXml = Feldsatz.InnerXml;
...
```

Comment: That looks more elegant i guess, but it's also not working a hundred percent because Index is of Type XmlNodeList. Which type do I need to give Index (the Internet says Enumarable but I cant get a hand on this)?

Comment: @Micha [`XmlNodeList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist) already implements the [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) interface ... Are you missing the `using System.Linq;` on the top of your script?

Comment: Thats what I firstly thought too. But it is declared and still giving me the error CS1061.